# undefined method 'each' for nil class in search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function

I have the following error:

> where line #14 raised:
>
> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
> Trace of template inclusion: app/views/cursos/search.html.erb

Do you know what can it be?

my view is:

```
 <% @cursose.each do |curso| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= curso.nombre %></td>
        <td>
          <ul  class="list-unstyled">
            <%= link_to 'Show', curso %>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

my controller is:

```
  def search
    @cursose = Curso.search(params[:search])
  end
```

my model is:

```
      def self.search(search)
    where("nombre LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end
```

I call function like this:

```
<div class="navbar-wagon-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">

  <%= form_tag(searchCursos_path, :method => "get", id: "search" , class: 'navbar-wagon-search' ) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Buscar Cursos", class: 'navbar-wagon-search-input'%>

      <button type="submit" class="navbar-wagon-search-btn">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have `@cursose` declared only one time in the search function. I saw that was an error but I have it ok.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried inspection the `@cursose` variable inside the controller to see if it's `nil` directly after the `search` call? Try adding a `raise @cursose.inspect` call directly under `@cursose = Curso.search(params[:search])` and see what is shown in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is saying that is because your `@cursose` variable is `nil`. Check whether the variable returns something. If it return `nil` then look for the part where you are initializing it.

Comment: i have the same sequence of code to search for users and it works.. where can i see the initialization of @cursose?

Comment: im initializing it inside the controller

Comment: In this case, make sure `@cursose` is not `[]`. This is where the error comes from. You can not iterate through an empty list. Try to cater for occasions when you do not have values for `params[:search]`

Comment: i have it ok, but i miss i had in private function. thanks!!